# If $H$ is a quotient of $G$, does there exist an $H$-extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ not contained in a $G$-extension?

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory, galois-cohomology, absolute-galois-group

Let $\phi\colon G\rightarrow H$ be a surjective homomorphism between finite groups. Assume that $\phi$ is not split, in other words there exists no homomorphism $\sigma\colon H\rightarrow G$ such that $\phi \circ \sigma = \text{Id}$.

**Question:** does there exists an $H$-extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ that is **not** contained in a $G$-extension?

Some remarks:

- If $A$ is a finite group and $k$ a field, an $A$-extension of $k$ is by definition a Galois extension $K/k$ with Galois group $A$.
- You may assume various strong forms of the inverse Galois problem over $\mathbb{Q}$, because I'm just trying to figure out whether this statement is true or not.
- The answer is affirmative when $\phi$ equals the quotient map $\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ if $p$ is prime: take a different prime $\ell$ such that the size of $\mathbb{F}_{\ell}^{\times}$ is divisible by $p$ but not $p^2$. Then one can check using the Kronecker-Weber theorem that the unique $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$-extension contained in $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$ (where $\zeta$ is an $\ell$-th root of unity) is not contained in a $\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}$-extension. I think a similar argument works when $G$ (and hence $H$) is abelian.
- The answer to this question can be no when $\mathbb{Q}$ is replaced by another number field. Indeed, if $k = \mathbb{Q}(i)$ then every quadratic extension lifts to a $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$-extension by Kummer theory.
- On the other hand, I would also be interested in the weaker question of whether there exists *some* number field $k$ which admits an $H$-extension that is not contained in a $G$-extension. There might be more hope to solve this unconditionally.

Any help and comments are appreciated!

Comment: Re $\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$: the same argument shows that if any $\ell$ as in your example ramifies in the $H$-extension $k$, then $k$ is not embeddable in a $G$-extension, since the local extension would have to be totally (tamely) ramified, which the hypothesis on $\ell$ precludes. My question is: what is the smallest examples of a non-split surjective map $G\to H$ that splits upon restriction to every soluble subgroup of $G$? For such a map, there won't be a local obstruction as above.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Alex! I agree that analyzing the local situation completely first is probably the most reasonable thing to do here.

Comment: This is not always true: any homomorphism from the absolute Galois group of any field to $GL_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$ lifts along the surjection $GL_2(\mathbb{Z}/p^2)\to GL_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$, see Proposition 3.3 in this paper by Khare-Larsen https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.01301v3 The proof is an application of Kummer theory as in your penultimate example. There is also this beautiful paper by Positselski https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.03880v1 where he gives a general technique for coming up with group surjections for which such automatic liftability happens.

Comment: (a small nitpick: perhaps in the formulation of the question you want to additionally require that the homomorphism from the Galois group of the ambient $G$-extension to that of the $H$-extension is conjugate to $\phi$? or else there would also be trivial examples when the answer is no: take $G=G'\times H$ with $\varphi$ induced by a non-split surjection $G'\to H$)

Comment: Fantastic, this is exactly what I'm looking for, thanks SashaP!

Comment: If you want you can post your first comment as an answer; it certainly answers the question.

Comment: @Jef I meant to convey that it seems to be an interesting problem to find out for which classes of group surjections the answer is negative, and I by no means gave a complete answer. Hopefully someone who knows more about this can describe the state of the art. For one thing, it could be helpful to see what Shafarevich's conjecture (that the absolute Galois group of $\mathbb{Q}^{ab}$ is free) predicts about your question.